# User reported that our app kill spotify background music, how to prevent that to happen?

Tags: android

So we got report that our app stop any music playing in the background like spotify, I also just tried it with youtube music and it also got killed

Our app is just a online f&b shop without any sound (but we use mediaPlayer to play logo animation in the beginning) and I dont think I've ever put some code to kill background music

is there any special setting I need to place in manifest to prevent this happening?

it is quite bewildering to me

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called Audio Focus. Sadly I couldn't find a developer page on how to prevent it.